# How to load empty grid on Extjs 4

Tags: null, grid, load, extjs4

I want to load and empty grid at the start of application. The grid should only be populated once the user selects a value from checkbox. I can't user autoLoad: false on store... is there any function like onLoad: false.. or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [default](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-autoLoad) *not* to load the store of a grid, so you literally need to do nothing.

I assume you are talking about a regular [Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store), with a [TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) things are a bit more complicated as you need to make sure the root node isn't expanded or cancel the load in the *onbeforeload* listener.

Comment: Thanks for your insight AndreKR... you are right... I have a store that pulls data from the controller... however it's not a tree... I have a combobox and a grid... and depending on the value selected on the combox, I populate my grid... but when the application loads at first, i want the grid to load nothing...

Comment: It won't, unless you tell it to (using `autoLoad: true` or `load()`).

Comment: That's a bummer... anyway, for others who might want to try something like this....I figured out how to not load anything by passing a parameter value of the combobox on load which is null. thanks for your time Andre